# Did the Silicon Graphics/SGI flight simulator (dog aka dogfight aka flight) have craft like X-Wings and Klingon Birds of Prey in any version?

Tags: sgi

[The Wikipedia page for SGI Dogfight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SGI_Dogfight) contains the following unsourced claim:

> In some intermediate version (between 1985 and 1995) aircraft inspired by Star Wars (X-wings, ...) were added. They disappeared in later versions.[citation needed]

Looking into this, I found that this claim was made in two edits from December 2015, by a now-deleted user.

The first of these read:

> In some intermediate version (between 1985 and 1995) aircrafts inspired by Star Wars (Klingon, Xwings, ...) were added. They disappeared in later versions. The Klingon had unlimited speed and could not be stalled.

The second edit removed the references to "Klingon" (presumably a 3d model intended to resemble a Bird-of-Prey.)

I can't find any source that backs up this claim, and nowhere online does anyone mention sci-fi spacecraft as playable "planes" in dog/flight.

Does anyone know if it really was possible to play as sci-fi spacecraft in any version of the flight software? If you have evidence/screenshots/citable sources, these would be greatly appreciated.

(Although I realise very few people are likely to have a Silicon Graphics workstation sitting around, or to have had a chance to use one!)

Comment: Pedantry note: Wikipedia users don't work like Stack Exchange users. The user isn't necessarily deleted, just nobody ever created a user page for them. (The Stack Exchange equivalent would be an empty About Me box.)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I know, but if the account's not deleted, the user's name doesn't show as red in the list of edits to a page. Plus there were never any more edits from that account.

Comment: I've seen cases where active users have red usernames in the list of edits to a page. That just means the link to their user page is a red link (a link to an article that does not exist).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Ah. I didn't realise. Even in those cases, though, I would have thought the user would have a valid talk page link?

Comment: That's usually created when someone uses a bot to send them a welcome message of some description. Though you're right, talk pages are often deleted when a user deletes their account… It appears that the talk page was never created in the first place, so it's still inconclusive.

Comment: Remember seeing a Klingon Cruiser in the flight simulator it dwarfed the end of the runway, snickering at an X-Wing fighter but then I had hacked a Colonial Viper (orig series with lasers) under GL2. The viper could go ballistic and was easy to land. Stalling is a function of wingspan/wingload - you lie. The 'aircraft' came from using a tool to convert model data on 4D-70's IIRC. Kinda doubt they were ever released to customers, would have been copyright by someone else and seeped in from someone's special effects rendering effort. Now there are models all over.